# taylor series for $f(z)=z\cos(2z)$ around $z_0= \pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Find a Taylor series for $f(z)=z\cos(2z)$ around $z_0= \pi$

I found that the Taylor series for $f(z)=\cos(2z)$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n4^n}{(2n)!}(z-\pi)^{2n}$. So do I just multiply in $z$ for $f(z)=z\cos(2z)$ to get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n4^n}{(2n)!}(z-\pi)^{2n}z$?

Comment: Of course not, since the Taylor series of $z$ around $z_0=\pi$ is not $z$ but $\pi+(z-\pi)$. Hence, one should multiply the Taylor series found for $\cos(2z)$ by $\pi+(z-\pi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is **a power series** for the function. You can do arithmetic with power series just like with the functions. Be careful if you need to evaluate such expressions though, as doing this can have surprising effects on the radius of convergence (not in your case since this function is analytic).

**However, it's not the Taylor polynomial**. You can tell this because Taylors polynomials hae the form $$\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n$$ which your formula doesn't have. An easy way to tell is to note that you have both $z$ and $z-\pi$ in your expression. You can modify it to obtain the desired for though, by multiplying by $\pi+(z-\pi)$ (instead of multiplying by $z$) and leaving the second term grouped.

Comment: Thank you! So is the final answer $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n4^n \pi}{(2n)!}(z-\pi)^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n4^n}{(2n)!}(z-\pi)^{2n+1}$?

Comment: @sucksatmath correct! You can simplify that to only have one summation by comparing the $n=i$ term in the first sum with the $n=i-1$ term in the second